# How do I mix different HTML templates?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to mix different HTML templates together. Basically, I have a prototype website that I want to use, and now I am trying to add different HTML codes from other HTML templates to kind of customize it that way. My question now is how do I get the CSS of the other HTML templates to fit my current website's CSS?

The goal of all this would be that I can just copy paste HTML codes from other templates to my current website.

Sorry if this is not accurate enough please let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You should not ask this on meta stack. meta.stackoverflow.com is for questions about stackoverflow.com, not for questions about HTML or CSS.

Comment: too broad Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays everyone thinks CSS is the language in which we write style rules. Actually, it's not (or at least it didn't use to be). `<style>` tags and the `style` attribute existed from the very beginning of HTML (when CSS didn't exist as a concept and term) and those were the only ways `style` properties of DOM nodes were changed <sup>1</sup>.

CSS actually means Cascading Style Sheets. And these sheets are files with `.css` extension. We now put styles into separate files to be able to load them (or not) in any template. So they don't belong to the template.

This doesn't mean you can't still add styles to markup using `<style>` tags or `style` attributes, but it's considered bad practice, and you should move those rules to a `.css` file, for two reasons:

a) to be able to load them in another template
b) to be able to easily change the order in which you load them, as reading order of stylesheets is quite important in CSS.

To load a stylesheet into an HTML template you have to use the `<link>` tag, typically inside `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link/to/stylesheet.css">
```

Most, if not all browsers will also read and apply it even if it's included in `<body>`, but you want to avoid it as it's likely to create [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

An alternative way of loading stylesheets is using [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40import) CSS rule inside another stylesheet:

```
@import url("path/to/another/stylesheet.css") screen and (min-width:768px);
```

Note an `@import` rule must precede all other types of rules, except `@charset`. Even though there is no technical penalty for using `@import` rules, the placement limitation as well as the additional complexity typically places them on the list of "don't"s in web development.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> To be technically correct, JavaScript was also usable for changing `style` properties of DOM nodes directly, just like it still is today. But back then JS was viewed as some sort of black-magic hacky "something", everyone thought enabling it in browser was similar to calling robbers and letting them know you're out of town for a few weeks and giving them specific details about where you keep valuables in the house - nobody used it, nobody trusted it.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks.